# My Spotlight opens the Applications folder instead of opening the application

Tags: macos, spotlight

My Spotlight, when I have selected an application, opens the "Applications" folder containing the application, instead of opening the application. I suspect I have a setting somewhere that is set in a weird way. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you holding CMD or OPT when that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem in Feb 2024 on Mac OS Sonoma. Solved it by:

1. Go to System Preferences > Siri & Spotlight
2. Deselect Documents from the long list of items that Spotlight is indexing

*[ Spotlight search now works correctly for applications ]*

3. Select again Documents

*[ Spotlight search still works correctly for applications ]*

This solved it for me.